# Looking for an approximation of $\mathbf{1}_{[0,t]}$ satisfying certain conditions.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequence-of-function

This question is somehow related to [my previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4452343/is-there-any-k-t-epsilon-to-mathbf1-0-t-such-that-fracddt-k-t) but asks for somewhat stronger conditions.

I am trying to find an approximation of the characteristic function of given interval satisfying the following conditions, but unfortunately I haven't been able to come up with anything.

> For $\epsilon>0$ and $t\in[0,T]$ let $K_t^{\epsilon}:[0,T]\to \mathbb
>  R$ be a deterministic function satisfying:
>
> - $K_t^{\epsilon}\longrightarrow \mathbf{1}_{[0,t]}$ in $L^2[0,T]$ as $\epsilon\to 0$;
> - There exists a constant $C$ such that \begin{align*}  \sup_{0\leq s,t\leq
>    T}\left(|\partial_tK_t^{\epsilon}(s)|+|\partial_t^2K_t^{\epsilon}(s)|\right)\leq
>    C; \end{align*}
> - $\frac{d}{dt}\|K_t^{\epsilon}\|^2_{L^2[0,T]}\longrightarrow 1$ as $\epsilon\to 0$, $\star$-weakly in $L^{\infty}[0,T]$.

I would really appreciate if you come up with an example, or at least some thought.

Comment: What is the role of $t$ in the function?

Comment: @Daron Well, $K_t^{\epsilon}$ is the kernel of an approximation for a Brownian motion $B_t^{\epsilon}=\int_0^TK_t^{\epsilon}(s)dB(s)$ that converges in mean-square to the actual Brownian motion $B_t$. Then $t$ is just the "time", but here we can simply treat it as a parameter